Show $\frac{1}{\pi^n}\zeta(n) \in \mathbb{Q}$ for even n
I am working on an exercise with aim to prove $\frac{1}{\pi^n}\zeta(n) \in \mathbb{Q}$ using Fourier series.
Here's the outline:
We first let $f_1(x) = x-\frac{1}{2}$, then we can express it with Fourier series:
$$f_1(x) = -\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(2\pi nx)}{\pi n}$$
Then we want to apply term-wise integration on the trigonometric stuff. We have to meet the requirement that $\int_0^1 f_1(x)dx = 0$, because we need to make sure the integrated function is also periodic.
Also, the constant term of Fourier series of $\int_0^xf(t)dt$ is given by:
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^x f(t)dt dx$$
Then we recursively define:
$$f_{n+1}(x) = \int_0^xf_{n}(x)dx - \int_0^1(\int_0^yf_n(t)dt)dy $$
We can show
$$ f_p(x) = \frac{1}{2^{p-1}\pi^p}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{"trigonometric \  function"}{n^p}  $$
I was stuck by the next step to show
$$\zeta(2p) = 2^{2p-1}\pi^{2p}\int_0^1f_p(x)^2dx$$
I really don't know how the $\int_0^1f_p(x)^2dx$ come from.
One attempt is that I simply take the square of each $f_p$ and organize the Fourier series using Cauthy products. For example,
$$f_2(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi^2}\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{\cos(2\pi nx)}{n^2} $$
$$f_2(x)^2 = \frac{1}{2^2 \pi^4} \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{\cos(2\pi nx)}{n^2} \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{\cos(2\pi nx)}{n^2}\\ = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \sum_{n = 1}^k \frac{\cos(2\pi xn)}{n^2} \frac{\cos(k-n+1)x}{(k-n+1)^2} $$
But I don't think I can make it cleaner and integrating this term doesn't seem to be doable.
At last we can show $\frac{1}{\pi^n}\zeta(n) \in \mathbb{Q}$ for even $n$, and that step is trivial.
Can anyone give me some help?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_identity
